# Exoplayer: Ошибка E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] err -1010. При воспроизведении .m3u8 (hls)

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Exoplayer не хочет показывать видео. Что за ошибка -1010? В дебаге пишет:

```
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err 
-1010
I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
```

VLC воспроизводит без проблем. Информация о потоке из VLC плеера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашли ответ на свой вопрос? Аналогичная проблема...

Comment: @Chekist нужно включить полный дебаг плеера, там будет подробное описание ошибки. Забыл уже как включал